# jquery mobile filterable widget select single element

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-filter

I'm using the JQuery mobile filterable widget. It works just like the demo.

However after the filtering has occured and the matched items are listed below the input, there is no way to select them.

I'm looking for selecting only one item from the matched items. That sounds like the most used function for a filterable widget, however it doesn't seem to support that function.

Am I missing something? Has anyone made it work as described above?

Comment: Have a look here: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/selectmenu-custom-filter/

Comment: well, the problem with this widget is that it places all items on the dom and then it filters them based on a match. I don't want that. I want a search textbox that shows only the list of matched items against a data source (an array) without having put anything previously on the dom.